# UWP WebView app, On-Screen keybaord would blink after a while of usage

Tags: webview, uwp, on-screen-keyboard

We have an app, that hosts a WebView which navigates to a website with forms/text fields. The app works on assigned access mode. The app works fine for couple of hours, but after a while it starts to blink and show white box

You can have a look at the video here:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ah2skpnDWn03iplWcWGUoFAUIb2W6g

The same issue happens on 3 different New Surface Pro machines.

Comment: This seems to be issue with the previous WIndows Build(Don't know exact version) and it was fixed in the latest build. You can check it on the latest Windows build.

Comment: @Dishant All the machines are updated to the latest firmware/updates.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not getting any help from Microsoft https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18803055/